# Change symbology in the legend- QGIS 2.14

Tags: symbology, point, buffer, legend, qgis-2.14

I work with a point layer. When i create a buffer for the point layer, i get this result:

[image]

[image]

My problem is that instead of circle buffer in the legend, i get a rectangle. 
I red this in order, maybe, to find an answer, but i didn't found:

[Is it possible to change legend symbols in the QGIS print composer legend?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/229617/is-it-possible-to-change-legend-symbols-in-the-qgis-print-composer-legend)

I can resolve it by:

- PrintScreen the layer panel and paste it the map composer as a jpg image.
- create a fictive layer that contains a circle, and represent it in the legend. The original layer will be removed from legend but will remain in the map extent.

How can i resolve this symbology problem with an elegant and automatic solution?

Comment: would it be possible to scale the size of the points with a value field? Of cause, this only works if you don't do any analyses with the buffer

Comment: sorry, i didn't understand you. can you give me an example, please?

Comment: if you don't need the buffer layer in the first place, then I would suggest that you scale the point symbol, so it fits the buffer size. Then you could either copy the point layer and display both in the legend or just display one.

Comment: nice solution but i seek for an automatic one

Answer (score 3):

You can try create style layer, which will be same as buffer.

[image: Legend]

In style properties:

[image: Style marker]

Comment: i need every layer represent separately